# Как получить код всех тегов <script> на web-странице с помощью CSS-селекторов?

Tags: c#, html, css, парсер

Есть фрагмент кода на С#. Как правильно выставить селекторы в `QuerySelectorAll` и `GetAttribute` чтобы занести в список код всех тегов  с web-страницы? Никак не могу разобраться. Библиотека : AngleSharp

```
List<string> scryptTags = new List<string>();

var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.ParseDocument(data);
foreach (IElement element in document.QuerySelectorAll("script"))
{
    scryptTags.Add(element.GetAttribute("script"));
}
```

Comment: Это какая библиотека?

Comment: Библиотека - AngleSharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение для `AngleSharp`:
Возвращает содержимое между тегов `<script></script>`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetContentOfScriptTags(string html)
{
    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.ParseDocument(html);
    var nodes = document.QuerySelectorAll("script");
    if (nodes != null)
    {
        var allScripts = new List<string>();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            allScripts.Add(node.Text());
        }

        return allScripts;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Возвращает ссылки на скрипт из `<script type='type' src='targetUrl'></script>`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLinksOfScriptTags(string source)
{
    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.ParseDocument(source);
    var nodes = document.QuerySelectorAll("script");
    if (nodes != null)
    {
        var scriptLinks = new List<string>();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            scriptLinks.Add(node.GetAttribute("src"));
        }

        return scriptLinks;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проект на AngleSharp. Хотелось бы пока все же попробовать сделать в рамках этой библиотеки.

Comment: Добавил решение для `AngleSharp`, достает всё между `<script></script>` и достаёт ссылки из `<script type='type' src='targetUrl'></script>`

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно. Спасибо большое!